# Query with UNION keyword runs very slow in mysql

Tags: mysql

Why is it that a query with UNION keyword runs very slow in mysql?

I have created a query using UNION keyword but everytime I execute it, it takes a long time before the output was displayed.

This is the query I used.

```
SELECT process_trained AS Training_Title, 
   org_party AS Organizing_Party, 
   duration AS Duration, 
   Concat(Date_format(sptrain_from, '%d-%b-%y'), " to ", 
   Date_format(sptrain_to, '%d-%b-%y'), "") AS SpecialTraining_Date, 
   trainor AS Trainor, 
   category AS Category, 
   training_type AS Training_Type, 
   train_id, 
   Date_format(cert_date, '%d-%b-%Y') AS Date_Certified, 
   Date_format(re_certdate, '%d-%b-%Y') AS Re_Certificaton, 
   remarks, 
   filename 
FROM(SELECT *, 
               cert_date AS cdate 
        FROM   tbldirtraining 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT *, 
               sptrain_from 
        FROM   tbldirtraining) jes 
WHERE  emp_id = '6555' 
       AND cdate <> '' 
ORDER  BY cdate;
```

Is there any possible way that can help on how to run this query faster.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show the execution plan?

Comment: how many rows are there in `tbldirtraining`? Also, why are you uniting the table with itself?

Comment: @Sebas...All in all there are 2053 rows in tbldirtraining and as you can see to above query I have used a WHERE clause to specify the training details to be displayed by the query. So the ID number 6555 must display 13 rows because he has 13 training, but everytime I use UNION or UNION ALL, the result was duplicated rows, so instead of 13 it becomes 26 that's why I put a condition 'WHERE cdate<>''' wherein cdate is the ALIAS i used for two united rows. I am uniting a columns in a table and those are date columns and they must be sorted simultaneously.

Comment: Please [edit] to provide your database schema, some sample data, and the output you'd like to get from that data. The query you've posted seems unnecessarily complex for what you're describing in the comments, but without more information it's pretty hard to help you find a better way to do things. (Based on what I can understand from the query and your comment, there's probably not even a need for a `UNION` here at all.)

Comment: @Sebas...Sir the above query returns a correct output, but my problem is the execution was very slow.

Comment: @KenWhite...Sir the keyword UNION is only way to sort two different date columns from that table that's why I used it, because I have to unite the cert_date and the sptrain_from column to sort them together.

Comment: Eliminate `union all`. Change `order by` to `order by least(cert_date, sptrain_from)`. This will keep the rows unique, and sort them by earlier date. See [least](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least) for details.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović...Sir I tried your suggestion and by this time I used ORDER BY GREATEST and the result was perfect. Thanks for the idea you had given me. It helps a lot :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
     SELECT process_trained AS Training_Title, 
 org_party AS Organizing_Party, 
 duration AS Duration, 
 Concat(Date_format(sptrain_from, '%d-%b-%y'), " to ", 
 Date_format(sptrain_to, '%d-%b-%y'), "") AS SpecialTraining_Date, 
 trainor AS Trainor, 
 category AS Category, 
 training_type AS Training_Type, 
 train_id, 
 Date_format(cert_date, '%d-%b-%Y') AS Date_Certified, 
 Date_format(re_certdate, '%d-%b-%Y') AS Re_Certificaton, 
 remarks, 
 filename 
FROM  tbldirtraining 
WHERE  emp_id = '6555' 
AND cert_date <> '' 
ORDER  BY cert_date desc,sptrain_from asc;
```

Comment: I have already tried that query but the output was sorted only by cert_date, what I want is to sort it both by cert_date and sptrain_from. Just like this--When the cert_date was 2011-01-25,2011-02-01 and the sptrain_from was 2011-01-22,2013-08-02, the output must be sorted like this: 2011-01-22, 2011-01-25, 2011-02-01,2013-08-02.

Comment: i didnt help if you add `sptrain_from` to order by as i edited ?

Comment: ahm. Actually sir no because I have already tried that one and the result wasn't the one I am expecting. But anyway, Thanks for the help you offered Sir :-)